# How to prevent Panorama scrolling from last item to first item in a Windows Phone 7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can it be prevented that, when the user is viewing the last PanoramaItem, that he can scroll further to the right? - which moves back to the the first PanoramaItem.
(and, vice-versa, preventing to scroll from the first to the last by swiping to the left)

I'm asking this because in my app I have a panorama-page with only 2 PanoramaItems. The user can scroll from one to the other by swiping to the left or to the right. I want to prevent that other animation when scrolling beyond the last PanoramaItem.
Is it possible?

Comment: An alternative approach could be to have a ScrollViewer - but then the question is: How to snap the view to certain positions? (to the first and to the second column)

Comment: Panoramas work best when they have between 4 & 7 items. Less than 3 will likley cause anomolies in the scrolling of the background and should be avoided. Have you considered using a different control?

Comment: Which control are you thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me that you perhaps you shouldn't be using the Panorama at all.  Looking at your other question about making the items smaller, it seems you want to push the Panorama beyond its designed purpose.

Perhaps you need is ScrollViewer with your two items (laid out using Grids) in a StackPanel with a horizontal orientation.

Comment: I'm trying to make something similar to the WP7 home screen (hubs and list of applications). Is that possible with a ScrollViewer. The view should snap to certain positions.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently how panorama is designed to work. There isn't a parameter to disable the capability.

Breaking from this behaviour would likely confuse users by introducing inconsistent behaviour between apps.

There are visual cues to indicate to the user that they are wrapping around with their scrolling action. The Title is displayed from the begining again and if your background image supports it, the join of the right side and left side indicates that the panorarma is wrapping around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the Windows Phone 7 home screen. You can swipe from the hubs to the list of applications and back. The behavior is different from a Panorama page. How can this be implemented? It would be consistent behavior on WP7 imo.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you'd go with a horizontal listbox containing two vertical listboxes, the left side you could use WrapPanel in the listbox to get the tile like effect. One challenge you're going to have though is snapping to each page. This question has come up before in other contexts, but as yet I don't recall anyone working on a solution to this publicly.

Comment: Thinking this through I can see why you've looked to Panorama. If you remove the background or disable the paralax effect, you're 95% there. The particularly challenging part of this puzzle is something you get for free.. which is the snapping. Granted, the wrap around breaks from the experience you're after. Unless you compromise on the wrap around, you may not have a choice than to take a more ground up approach.