# Controlling forward and backward navigation in a windows phone panorama application

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I have 5 panorama items inside a panorama. (I will call them item1 ...item5)

(A) By default, the user will be able to navigate the items in the order:

item1 -> item2 -> item3 -> item4 -> item5 -> item1 (and cycle continues)

(B) The backward navigation would be like:

item1 -> item5 -> item4 -> item3 -> item2 -> item1

I want to block the backward and forward navigation at the first and last item respectively.

What I want is that when the user is at item1, he should not be allowed to navigate back to item5 as described in (B). Also, when the user is at item5, he should not be allowed to move directly to item1.

Essentially, I want to break the cycle at the ends. How do I do this?

Thanks
-Abhinav-

Comment: Fouond some explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620896/how-to-prevent-panorama-scrolling-from-last-item-to-first-item-in-a-windows-phone

Comment: I can see reasons for doing this, but consider that most (if not all) apps using the panorama control have a looping behavior users have come to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Found the below link which gives the answer to the same question

[How to prevent Panorama scrolling from last item to first item in a Windows Phone 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620896/how-to-prevent-panorama-scrolling-from-last-item-to-first-item-in-a-windows-phone)